# Un verbe au subjonctif sans « que » ?

Tags: verbes, subjonctif

> Les têtes se courbèrent sur les cartons, et le nouveau resta pendant
>   deux heures dans une tenue exemplaire, quoiqu'il y eût bien, de temps
>   à autre, quelque boulette de papier lancée d'un bec de plume **qui
>   vînt** s'éclabousser sur sa figure.

(*Madame Bovary*, Chapitre I)

La forme *qu'il vînt* est l'imparfait subjonctif du verbe *venir*. Mais dans cette phrase le verbe *vînt* est utilisé sans *que*. Pourquoi ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Le subjonctif est courant dans les subordonnées qui ont un rôle de caractérisation.

Autre exemple:

> J'aimerais une voiture qui ait une belle couleur.

Dans cette phrase la couleur est ce qui importe. On fait une présupposition sur les voitures possibles.

C'est différent de:

> J'aimerais une voiture qui a une belle couleur.

Ici la voiture a pu être choisie pour une autre raison, il est simplement précisé qu'elle a une belle couleur.

Comment: je dirais aussi que l'existence de la voiture dont on parle est en doute, et c'est pour ça qu'on y utilise le subjonctif

Comment: @constrom: Non ce n'est pas pour ça, il y a des voitures de toutes les couleurs. Si tu préfères, regarde l'exemple donné dans la question il n'y a absolument aucun doute.

Answer (score 3):

I do think that the kind of subjunctive in this sentence is what Glanville Price calls the [generic subjunctive](https://books.google.ro/books?id=p0lZAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT286&lpg=PT286&dq=%22generic%20subjunctive%22&source=bl&ots=kVd_cFtO-J&sig=U9GqZnRybpM8k3-8OEWcq3zWf0o&hl=ro&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig49uHjMXUAhXMbZoKHeoUDLMQ6AEIWDAG#v=onepage&q=%22generic%20subjunctive%22&f=false), which is to be found in relative clauses.

This particular type of subjunctive, as Glanville Price further explains, relates to "a possible member or members of a class."

The member of the class of "paper," which makes the subjunctive the appropriate choice in this context, is "[une] boulette de papier," whose indefiniteness is only emphasized by "quelque."

If you think I am right, please let me know by upvoting my self-answer...

Edit to add the examples from Glanville Price's *Comprehensive French Grammar*:

> An example will help to make this clear. If I ask someone: ‘Could
>   you show me the road that leads to the station?’, the relative
>   clause ‘that leads . . . etc.’ describes a particular road that I know (or, at any rate, that I assume) actually exists – the French
>   equivalent has the indicative, *Pourriez-vous m’indiquer le chemin
>   qui conduit à la gare* ? Likewise, if I say: ‘I am looking for a road
>   [i.e. a road that I know exists and that I am describing] that leads
>   to the station’, the French equivalent is: *Je cherche un chemin
>   qui conduit à la gare*. But if I ask: ‘Could you show me a road
>   that leads to the station?’ (i.e. I am in fact enquiring whether any
>   such road exists), or if I say: ‘I am looking for a road that [if such a road exists] leads to the station’, the relative clause rather than describing a particular road indicates the type of road that I want,i.e. it relates to any members of the class (which may or may not exist) of ‘roads leading to the station’. In such cases, French has the subjunctive, viz. *Pourriez-vous m’indiquer un chemin qui conduise à la gare ?*, or *Je cherche un chemin qui conduise à la gare*. Likewise, the subjunctive is of course used when the existence of the class in question is represented as hypothetical, as in ‘If you know a road that leads to the station’, *Si vous connaissez un chemin qui conduise à la gare*, or is denied , as in ‘There is no road that leads to the station’, Il n’y a pas de chemin qui conduise à la gare.

Comment: It is, I've quoted the explanation that follows what you mention from  from *Glanville's Comprehensive French Grammar*, I think it makes the concept clearer than in Flaubert's sentence.