# Why is subjunctive being used here

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif, modalité

I came across the following

> ...ses yeux verts pétillants, bien que, pour l'instant, ils soient rouges et larmoyants

I do not understand why the second part is in the subjunctive tense. My understanding is that the subjunctive is used for wishes and unreal events but if I understand correctly the write is stating that **the eyes are red and watery at the moment** and there is nothing unreal about it.

**EDIT**

Here is the chapter of Cinquante nuances de Grey.

http://m.chapitres.actualitte.com/lecture/cinquante-nuances-de-grey-james-e-l/2002

> Kate est blottie dans le canapé du salon. — Ana, je suis désolée.
>   Cette interview, je cours après depuis neuf mois. Si j'annule, je
>   n'aurai pas d'autre rendez-vous avant six mois et, d'ici là, on aura
>   quitté la fac. Je suis la rédac' chef, je ne peux pas me permettre de
>   planter le journal. Je t'en supplie, ne me laisse pas tomber,
>   m'implore-t-elle d'une voix enrouée. Elle fait comment ? Même malade,
>   elle est à tomber avec ses cheveux blond vénitien impeccablement
>   coiffés **et ses yeux verts pétillants, bien que, pour l'instant, ils**
>   **soient rouges et larmoyants**. Je refoule une bouffée de compassion. —
>   Évidemment que je vais y aller, Kate. Retourne te coucher. Tu veux de
>   l'Actifed ou un Doliprane ? — Actifed, s'il te plaît. Tiens, voici mes
>   questions et mon dictaphone. Tu appuies ici pour enregistrer. Prends
>   des notes, je décrypterai. — Ce mec, je ne sais rien de lui, dis-je en
>   tentant vainement de réprimer ma panique croissante. — Avec mes
>   questions, tu t'en sortiras très bien. Allez, vas-y. Tu as une longue
>   route à faire. Il ne faut pas que tu sois en retard. — O.K., j'y vais.
>   Retourne te coucher. Je t'ai préparé de la soupe, tu pourras la faire
>   réchauffer plus tard.

Comment: Internal links to older questions related to this: https://french.stackexchange.com/q/11/13100 & https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26043/le-subjonctif-est-il-toujours-hypoth%C3%A9tique

Comment: One more: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26052/un-verbe-au-subjonctif-sans-que

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the statement of the question, it is not obvious the level of mastering of the French language of the OP, so I have split my answer starting from some preliminary notes going up to a specialized publication.

### General Remarks

> ...ses yeux verts pétillants, bien que, pour l'instant, ils soient rouges et larmoyants.

- There are some subordinating conjunctions that require the
  subjunctive mood. Among them is bien que. Subordinating conjunctions,
  are used to join a subordinating clause (dependent clause) to main
  clauses. In particular, bien que belongs to the so called opposition
  conjunctions that include also malgré que, sauf que, sans que...

> Quoiqu’il fasse froid, il se baigne. = Bien qu’il fasse froid, il se baigne.

See, e.g.,

http://lebonusage.over-blog.com/article-la-proposition-concessive-73059655.html

from where the following passage is gleaned:

> La concessive se met au subjonctif avec : "bien que, quoique, encore
>   que, sans que" (Il en est très amoureux sans qu'il y paraisse. Il est
>   sorti bien qu'il soit malade).

From this reference 
https://www.neoscript.fr/astuces-de-la-langue-francaise/180-indicatif-ou-subjonctif.html

We read:

> En revanche, certaines locutions sont toujours suivies du subjonctif.
>   C'est notamment le cas d'afin que (« Afin que tu saches »), à moins
>   que, avant que, bien que, de crainte que, encore que, jusqu'à ce que,
>   pourvu que, quoi que.

From another reliable source

https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/regles-orthographe/afin-que-quoique-indicatif-ou-subjonctif/

One reads:

> Règle (comment ne plus commettre cette erreur) Après « afin que », «
>   pour que », « jusqu’à ce que », « bien que », « quoique », le verbe
>   est toujours au subjonctif.
>
> > Il vous serre la main, bien que vous soyez son adversaire.
> >
> > Je ferais n’importe quoi pour qu’il sourie.

Yet another one

http://mamiehiou.over-blog.com/article-bien-que-indicatif-subjonctif-ou-conditionnel-quel-mode-choisir-79554147.html

We read:

> Bien que tous les torts soient de mon côté, je n'en tiendrai aucun
>   compte.
>
> Ma décision n'a pas varié d'un iota bien que tu aies fait ton cinéma
>   pendant quatre jours.

Some other relevant  references

http://laits.utexas.edu/tex/gr/tas5.html

https://www.frenchtoday.com/blog/french-verb-conjugation/understanding-french-subjunctive

http://www2.snh.be/frans/conjugaison/temps/emploisubjonctifindicatif.htm

http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4238

https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-25454.php

From the last one

> indiquant une restriction, une opposition : on emploie le subjonctif.
>   La restriction inverse la relation de cause attendue.
>
> Bien que Pierre
>   soit venu, je suis sortie.
>
> Subjonctif car la venue de Pierre aurait
>   dû me faire rester. C'est le décalage entre ce qui est attendu et ce
>   qui se passe qui entraîne l'emploi du subjonctif.
>
> Certaines locutions formées avec que sont toujours suivies du
>   subjonctif :  à condition que, afin que, à moins que, à supposer que,
>   au lieu que, bien que, d'aussi loin que, de crainte que, de façon que,
>   de manière que, de peur que, du plus loin que, en admettant que, en
>   attendant que, encore que, en sorte que, jusqu'à ce que, moyennant
>   que, peu s'en est fallu que, pour autant que, pour peu que, pour que,
>   pourvu que, quel que (et quelque... que), qui que, quoique (et quoi
>   que), avant que , sans que, si bien que, si peu que, si tant est que,
>   soit que... soit que, supposé que, trop... pour que  (et malgré que:
>   cette dernière est à éviter car impropre sauf lorsque cette locution
>   est suivie d''avoir' -> malgré qu'il ait ... Néanmoins elle est
>   employée de plus en plus régulièrement et doit être citée. Elle est
>   obligatoirement suivie du subjonctif).

Two more references

http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/732.html

http://grammaire.reverso.net/1_1_20_Le_subjonctif.shtml

### When bien que is not a conjunction

- When bien que does not imply opposition it does not require subjunctive.

> Je pense bien qu'il t'aime.

---

### An ongoing debate

- Regarding bien que as conjunction there is an ongoing debate between
  those stating that one **must** use the subjunctive and others who state
  that bien que may be followed by the indicative according to the context. See for instance
  here

https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/chroniq/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_titls&page=9U66xqoK0nJk.html

- But I think this concerns, for the time being, those that master
  sufficiently enough the French Grammar, if not the purists. The books
  of French grammar that I possess do not even mention this.

E.g., copying from [French Grammar in Context](https://www.routledge.com/French-Grammar-in-Context-4th-Edition/Jubb-Rouxeville/p/book/9780415706681) (upper intermediate/advanced students)

> Various types of conjunction trigger the use of the subjunctive. These
>   include: • concessive, e.g. bien que • expressions of purpose, e.g.
>   pour que • expressions of restriction, e.g. à moins que • expressions
>   of fear, e.g. de peur que The following examples occur in the text:
>   bien que de multiples raisons puissent exister (lines 5–6) pour que se
>   constituent (lines 23–4; also 30–1; 37) à moins que deux V. n’existent
>   (line 15) de peur que le gamin ne finisse (lines 26–7)

And here is a passage from Grammaire-Les Indispensables (Dubois et Lagane, Larousse, 2009).

> Dans les propositions subordonnées conjonctives ou relatives, le
>   subjonctif peut s'employer quand la subordonnée exprime une idée : ►
>   de but : Je lui montre la lettre afin qu il comprenne toute I affaire
>   ; ► de concession : Bien que la pièce fût médiocre, on ne s'ennuyait
>   pas ; ► de condition : Réglons cela, à moins que vous ne vouliez
>   réfléchir ; ► de conséquence : Ce n'est pas si compliqué qu'on ne
>   puisse comprendre

Ibid.:

> Les conjonctions de subordination relient une proposition subordonnée
>   à une autre proposition dont elle dépend, en particulier à une
>   principale. Ces conjonctions expriment : (...) ► la concession - *
>   bien que quoique : Bien que cet échec fût grave, elle ne se découragea
>   pas.

---

### Price's (A) Comprehensive French Grammar

- For the sake of completeness, here is the relevant article from
  Price's (A) Comprehensive French Grammar. The author does talk about bien que
  plus subjunctive/indicative.

**The subjunctive after conjunctions formed on the basis of que**

> Conjunctions meaning ‘although’, of which the commonest are quoique
>   (note that this is written as one word) and bien que, e.g.:
>
> Il le fera
>   bien que ce soit défendu. =  He will do it although it is forbidden.
>
> Quoique mon frère ait reçu ma lettre, il ne vient pas. = Although my
>   brother has received my letter, he is not coming.
>
> *(The reality of the
>   event may well be accepted, but it is discounted – e.g. in the second
>   of these examples it is accepted that the letter has been received,
>   but in spite of that fact, the brother is not coming.)*
>
> **Bien que and
>   quoique occasionally take the indicative or conditional when ‘though’
>   is almost the same as ‘but’ e.g.:**
>
> Il nous faut le faire, bien que nous
>   n’y gagnerons rien. = We must do it, though/but we shall gain nothing by
>   it.
>
> **but, generally speaking, the subjunctive should be used.**
>
> Other
>   conjunctions meaning ‘although’ and taking the subjunctive are encore
>   que (exclusively literary) and malgré que (familiar, and frowned on by
>   some grammarians).
>
> Note that alors que and tandis que, both
>   meaning ‘whereas’, always take the indicative.

---

### Bien que+conditionnel (emploi erroné ?):

See

http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/742.html#2

> D’une manière générale, l’emploi du conditionnel est impossible dans
>   les concessives in­tro­dui­tes par bien que, alors qu’il est fréquent
>   en finnois après vaikka. On entend pourtant assez fréquemment des
>   phrases avec bien que suivi du conditionnel (fréquent à l’oral), mais
>   c’est en principe in­cor­rect :
>
> La direction de l’axe magnétique dans l’espace change donc constamment
>   et rapidement, mais n’est jamais orientée vers le soleil bien que ce
>   serait brièvement possible à d’autres points de l’orbite de la planète
>   [extrait d’un traité d’astronomie]. Ils ont sans doute eu raison de
>   rentrer, bien que ça aurait été intéressant de passer un an à
>   l’étranger.
>
> Si on veut absolument exprimer le conditionnel dans un contexte
>   concessif, on peut couper la phrase et uti­li­ser une cons­truc­tion
>   paratactique avec adverbe :
>
> La direction de l’axe magnétique dans l’espace change donc constamment
>   et rapidement, mais n’est jamais orientée vers le soleil ; ce serait
>   cependant brièvement possible à d’autres points de l’orbite de la
>   planète. Ils ont sans doute eu raison de rentrer ; ça aurait pourtant
>   été intéressant de passer un an à l’étranger.
>
> À l’écrit, on uti­li­se le subjonctif, qui contient l’idée de
>   futur/éventuel/irréel :
>
> La direction de l’axe magnétique dans l’espace change donc constamment
>   et rapidement, mais n’est jamais orientée vers le soleil bien que cela
>   soit brièvement possible à d’autres points de l’orbite de la planète
>   Ils ont sans doute eu raison de rentrer, encore que / quoique à mon
>   avis il eût été intéressant de passer un an à l’étranger.

---

### Article: Subjunctive or Indicative Form

https://journals.openedition.org/pratiques/2697

Comment: No dimitris. *Bien que* does not *require*. You *may* choose the subjunctive. If you want to.

Comment: Avant de modifier votre réponse vous pourriez prendre un certain temps ; il y a une nouvelle opinion, contraire à la mienne, et qui est celle que vous aviez ; voir la réponse de 5915961T.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu parler de « préposition adverbiale » ( «adverbial préposition » dans votre réponse) ; de plus il s'agit simplement de l'adverbe « bien » dans la principale (Je crois bien) et de la conjonction de subordination « que » dans la subordonnée (qu'il t'aime) ; il ne faut parler que d'éviter de confondre (et c'est pour les débutants, pas un gros titre).

Comment: By the way, you should say "the indicative" not "indicative"; it's a so called "sing noun", as "sun" and "moon"; you always say "the sun", "the moon".

Comment: You must be talking about prepositional adverbs, usually refered to as adverbial particles; you find those only in English, not in French. https://www.thoughtco.com/prepositional-adverb-1691528

Answer (score 1):

I can second your non-understanding. But... not the argument.

In the case of sentences of the kind *P1 bien que P2* you get two contradictary judgements. *Ses yeux sont verts / Ses yeux sont rouges.*
In this precise case, P2 is some sort of *rectifying concession*

In such cases, usually, (Damourette & Pichon -> Mary-Annick Morel...) the mode will indicate the locutor's position regarding P2.

- P2 is made by another source / the locutor simply acknowleges it but does not necessarily endorse it. => subjunctive
- The locutor entirerly endorses / is the author of the judgement. => indicative. :

As in *La poudre s'est trouvée subitement mouillée bien qu'il ne pleuvait pas*, the locutor being responsible for both judgements (eyes green / eyes red) the above logic should have governed indicative :

*ses yeux sont verts, bien que, pour l'instant, il **sont** rouges* exactly as you said it in english. You are correct.

It should however be stated that (and, it seems particularily needed to insist here) in the particular case of *rectifying concessions* **mode is absolutely not constrained.**
While being himself responsible for both judgements, the locutor might want to insist on the correction, on the impact of P2 on P1 and keep indicative for P2. Or... contrarily, show a simple and temporary discontinuity in the narration plan.

So, in order to precisely answer your question : **Why is subjunctive being used ?**

I suspect that is the reason why the author chose the subjonctive here, P2 does not fundamentally / definitely contradicts P1. **P2's value is just... accidental.**

Comment: Je ne maîtrise pas suffisamment le français mais je peux vérifier que même me livres de grammaire du français disent que le subjonctif suit bien que  quand bien que est conjonction.

Comment: Vois les liens rajoutés et ma réponse éditée et aussi http://www.languefrancaise.net/forum/viewtopic.php?id=5498 Mon idée est que c'est une lutte entre subjonctif et indicatif mais ça, je trouve, ne concerne pas ceux qui apprennent le français (débutants, faux débutants...)

Comment: @dimitris : Tu me sembles avoir acquis un niveau suffisant en français pour pouvoir passer... à d'autres lectures.

Comment: C'est pas pour moi:-)! The question states :  "I do not understand why the second part is in the subjunctive tense. My understanding is that the subjunctive is used for wishes and unreal events..." I thought that the user does not know about the conjunctions that require the subjonctive, therefore, my response should cover the fundamentals. See all my references. All state clear that bien que (concession) requires subjonctive. I understand your point of view, I thank you for your kind comments regarding my level of French, I can follow the debate here...

Comment: https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/chroniq/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_titls&page=9U66xqoK0nJk.html or the comments of Grevisse but I think that a no native French speaker should use the subjunctive since "bien que je croyais qu'ils vivaient en Afrique" may still surprise a French natif.

Comment: I found that Price's (A) Comprehensive French Grammar talks about indicative and bien que meaning "but". See the edit.

Comment: @dimitris : cf ton comm. 1 : Il n'est aucune sorte de lutte entre subjonctif et indicatif. Si lutte il y a, elle est entre les grammairiens qui disent "on doit" et les grammairiens qui tiennent leur discipline pour un **outil**. Un merveilleux outil **au service** de celui qui écrit.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.I edited this statement in my answer.

Comment: Règle (comment ne plus commettre cette erreur) 
Après « afin que », « pour que », « jusqu’à ce que », « bien que », « quoique », le verbe est toujours au subjonctif.

> Il vous serre la main, bien que vous soyez son adversaire.

> Je ferais n’importe quoi pour qu’il sourie.                                  https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/regles-orthographe/afin-que-quoique-indicatif-ou-subjonctif/

Comment: À noter que cette "Difficulté (est) traitée dans le module Projet Voltaire **EXCELLENCE**" (!)

Comment: @dimitris : Tu cherches quoi avec toutes tes citations issues des même sources ? À me démontrer que tu as raison ? Bon! Alors tu as raison! C'est dit! N'en parlons plus. Si ton but est, en revanche d'en savoir plus sur ce qu'il en **est**... Tu passes à la lecture des références données en début de ma réponse tu reviendras ensuite me dire... **ta** conclusion. Quelle qu'elle soit, je te le promets, là! Elle sera justifiée.

Comment: Je veux seulement dire que ça ne concerne (pour le moment) que des personnes avec un niveau de maîtrise du français comme le tien ou bien des personnes comme moi que j'aime chercher la grammaire française. Je ne souhaite pas prétendre le "smart guy". Je donne toutes ces références pour montrer quelle est la situation dans les sources "down-to-earth".  Je n'ai pas voulu t'insulter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87697/discussion-between-acoswt-and-dimitris).

Answer (score 1):

« Je pense bien qu'il t'aime. – Here bien que is an adverbial preposition. » C'est vraiment n'importe quoi ! Il s'agit d'une simple juxtaposition, pas d'une catégorie grammaticale ! En fait, la proposition subordonnée complétive est : « qu'il t'aime », complément de la principale « Je pense » dont la signification du verbe est renforcée par l'adverbe « bien » ; si on remplace ce dernier par « assurément », *assurément que* est aussi la simple succession des mots de la phrase !

Pour en revenir à la question, les subordonnées circonstancielles de concession (les concessives) emploient le subjonctif. Celui-ci est donc entre autres la marque du doute, mais aussi de la concession au sens grammatical.

On notera que ce mode étant un peu en perte de vitesse en français moderne (ça arrive, cf. l'optatif en grec …), certaines personnes moins éduquées ont tendance à faire suivre *bien que* ou *quoique* de l'indicatif – à l'inverse, un grand nombre de locuteurs même éduqués emploient le subjonctif après « après que », sans doute par contagion de « avant que ».

Assez compliqué tout cela, je suis bien content que le français soit ma langue maternelle, content bien que j'aie passé des années d'école primaire à conforter et structurer son apprentissage   ;–)

donc bon courage à tous les étrangers qui s'y mettent !!   ;–(

(per aspera ad astra, inquiunt)

Comment: Vous pourriez peut être vous intéresser à la discussion entre aCOSwt  et dimitris sur cette question de subjonctif et nous éclairer sur votre façon de penser en ce qui la concerne.

Comment: Vous dites « certaines personnes moins éduquées ont tendance à faire suivre …» ; c'est assez bizarre : je ne considère pas mon niveau d'éducation comme exceptionnel et toute ma vie j'ai trouvé naturel l'emploi du subjonctif après « bien que » et l'ai respecté scrupuleusement ; je ne me suis pas non plus posé de question au sujet de cet emploi ; ce n'est que de nos jours, comme justement je m'intéresse à cette question, que quoi qu'il en soit de la gène que crée la force de l'habitude lorsque j'utilise l'indicatif, je trouve dans certains cas l'usage du subjonctif complètement illogique.