# « Mais que » (avec valeur temporelle : quand, dès que) en français parlé du Québec etc. : précisions ?

Tags: conjonctions, subjonctif, québec, régionalismes, concordance-des-temps

> *°**Mais que*** s'emploie pour *quand, dès que* dans le français parlé (ou dans des écrits qui le reflètent) en Normandie, au Québec et en
>   Louisiane, suivi ordinairement du subjonctif [Usage ancien (encore
>   chez [MALHERBE](https://books.google.ca/books?id=Q9oVAAAAMAAJ&lpg=PA145&dq=l'affection%20avec%20laquelle%20j'embrasserai%20votre%20affaire&pg=PA145#v=onepage&q=l'affection%20avec%20laquelle%20j'embrasserai%20votre%20affaire&f=false) et RACAN : cf. Brunot, Hist., t. III, p. 394) que
>   [Vaugelas](https://books.google.ca/books?id=aqZBAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA262#v=onepage&q&f=false), pp. 162-163, rebutait comme pop.)
>
> [ *Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Boeck, 14<sup>e</sup>, §
>   1136 R7 ]

Ce qui choquait Vaugelas entre autres, *Malherbe* dans ses lettres etc. :

> L'affection avec laquelle j'embrasserai votre affaire, *mais que* je
>   sache ce que c'est, vous témoignera que vous y deviez aller avec plus
>   de liberté
>
> Vous aurez le grand *Roman des Chevaliers de la gloire*, *mais qu*'il
>   soit achevé d'imprimer. ([Malherbe](https://books.google.ca/books?id=McIZAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA263&lpg#v=onepage&q&f=false))

On trouve des [exemples](https://books.google.ca/books?id=GXq5Hi-ENfgC&lpg=PA106&vq=%22mais%20que%22&pg=PA137) d'emplois de *mais que* (quand, dès que) suivis de l'indicatif et du subjonctif au 14<sup>e</sup>, mais on parle surtout du subjonctif pour le futur dans l'article Wikipédia sur le [français québécois](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ais_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois#Futur). Je peux facilement imaginer à l'oral au Québec :

> *Mais que* tu aies/auras fini, tu me le diras.

Ce n'est pas employé à l'écrit. On dit *dans le français parlé au Québec*, est-ce généralisé ou populaire, courant dans tous les styles, avec tous les groupes, est-ce évalué (négativement) par la personne qui l'emploie et l'évaluation est-elle la même pour le futur antérieur et le subjonctif passé, voire avec le passé composé (*tu as fini*) ; l'emploi avec le subjonctif est-il vraiment plus fréquent que celui à l'indicatif ; qu'en est-il ailleurs où c'est employé ; incidemment lequel des temps concorde le mieux dans la phrase ?

Comment: Il y a quelque chose d'illogique dans cet usage : il est dit que le sens est  « quand » ou « dès que » mais le subjonctif avec ces mots-là est du pur non-sens.

Comment: @LPH pas de discrimination prescriptive, SVP. La "logique" en langue est une illusion absolue. Je peux vous donner un plein paquet d'examples où le subjonctif est *obligatoire* pour des événement confirmés,

Comment: @Circeus Je ne comprends pas très bien ce que vous voulez prouver ; mon commentaire est tout à fait en accord avec la préoccupation de nombre de personnes écrivant sur ce site, celles-ci s'attachant à exiger que l'usage du subjonctif relève d'une nécessité logique ; un exemple de cette position est la question de décider s'il faut le subjonctif après « bien que » ; voir par exemple cette [réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/33201/17649) à ce sujet, (lorsque la BDL nous dit qu'après « bien que » le subjonctif est généralement employé) ; les discussions de cette sorte sont nombreuses.

Comment: @Circeus Je dois ajouter que mon commentaire n'est pas de nature prescriptive ; je ne dis pas que le subjonctif ne doive pas être utilisé ; je pense  que personne ne contestera que la   nécessité  savoir de si oui ou non le subjonctif est utilisé judicieusement est réelle et que ce savoir  fait partie de la connaissance linguistique de l'usage ; on ne peut pas ignorer cet état de choses : la question « Pourquoi  utiliser le subjonctif dans cet usage ? » est immédiate ; qu'est-ce qu'il faut répondre ?

Comment: @LPH : « [L’usage est l’arbitre souverain des langues.](https://books.google.ca/books?id=aqZBAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA10) ». ;-)

Answer (score 2):

C'est un usage pas entièrement oral, mais définitivement familier (certainement moins fréquent à l'écrit que le conditionnel après *si*, ou la conditionnelle avec un infinitif passé). Je ne suis pas certain si le futur ou le subjonctif sont plus fréquent (j'aimerais dire le subjonctif, mais je crois que je ne suis pas très bon juge de mon usage spontané dans ce cas...). Malheureusement, ce n'est pas un construction pour laquelle il est possible de googler des exemples.

Comment: Tu as vu ça à l'écrit dans un texte contemporain où on ne rapporte pas l'oral (peux-tu donner un exemple) ? Trouves-tu que c'est marqué ou stigmatisé et trouves-tu que c'est le cas davantage pour le futur ou ce serait autant familier les deux et que penses-tu du passé composé ? Incidemment, as-tu remarqué si tu prononçais _que tu aies_ comme le subj. présent d'aller (_ailles_) et si oui, est-ce que ça ne connote pas le futur comme _tu vas avoir (fini)_ le ferait ?

Comment: @suiiurisesse Il n'y a pas de doute, ce « sens de la formulation », que j'appellerai plutôt « notion de la correspondance contextuelle » est un principe dominant ; c'est ce qui l'emporte dans la perpétuation de telles formes du langage ; l'usage est une chose et Vaugelas était je crois l'un des premiers à se plaindre de ses caprices mais je ne crois pas qu'il soit roi : l'usage tel que la langue des campagnes le montre est loin de déplacer l'usage général, c'est le contraire qui se passe  (pour les créoles il ne s'agit pas de déplacement mais d'un fossé infranchissable), (champ 1)

Comment: @suiiurisesse et cela est la preuve que tout n'est pas sacré dans l'usage. Il n'y a aucun doute que de nos jours on peut forcer  **une partie de l'usage** au moyen des médias et c'est un processus non reconnu en cours d'utilisation ; on sait par ailleurs que n'importe quoi ne peut pas être instillé  n'importe quand dans la façon de penser de la population : une certaine partie de ce qui est forcé reste de la langue morte pour une population qui ne peut pas se résoudre à en faire un usage autre que passif, (champ 2)

Comment: @suiiurisesse  celui de la lecture, les termes proposés ayant, entre autre défauts possibles, une qualité artificielle qui les déconnecte du bon sens associé à l'expression standard. (fin)