# Usage de « nous »

Tags: pronoms-personnels

> (texto envoyé par un ami) Tu vas au basket ?
>
> (réponse après quelques heures) Désolé. Je viens de voir ton message. Nous étions à la mer. Nous sommes rentrés chez nous il y a peu de temps. Nous irons au basket demain.

Avec « nous » j'ai indiqué « ma famille et moi ». Cet emploi de « nous » est-il compréhensible dans ce contexte ? Est-ce que j'aurais dû utiliser « on » ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - Cet emploi de « nous » est-il compréhensible dans ce contexte ?

Oui, bien sûr. *Nous* est toujours parfaitement compréhensible en français.

> - Est-ce que j'aurais dû utiliser « on » ?

Tu n'aurais pas **dû**, car ce n'est pas obligatoire et que tout le monde comprend ton message, mais tu aurais **pu** car l'écrasante majorité des francophones natifs auraient utilisé **on** dans un SMS, le registre habituel étant celui du français parlé familier d'où la première personne du pluriel a essentiellement disparu<sup>1</sup>.

Voici par exemple ce que j'aurais probablement écrit à ta place :

> Désolé. Je viens de voir ton message. On était à la mer et on vient juste de rentrer à la maison. On ira au basket demain.

On pourrait aussi rencontrer des abréviations de ce style :

> dsl: désolé
>   msg: message
>   2m1: demain

mais inutile de les utiliser, à part *msg* qui est assez courant, si elles ne font pas partie des habitudes des ses correspondants...

<sup>1</sup> <sub>[Wikipedia: On](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/on) : En français courant, *on* a déjà remplacé *nous* comme pronom clitique du sujet de la première personne du pluriel. Selon L. R. Waugh, *on* est utilisé dans 99 % des cas, et *nous* seulement dans 1 % des cas</sub>

Answer (score 4):

L'usage de "nous" était tout à fait correct dans ce contexte. Il était possible de supposer qu'il s'agissait de votre famille, bien qu'il eut pu s'agir de d'autres personnes. "On" me semble encore moins précis car il peut aussi signifier des gens autres que la personne qui s'exprime (vous en l'occurence).

Answer (score -2):

« Nous » n'est pas considéré comme étant idiomatique par certains et ils insisteront sur le fait que le pronom « on » doit être utilisé. En fait, une vaste majorité de Français utilise « on » dans ce contexte. Ma façon de voir n'est pas tout à fait celle-là cependant, bien que, moi-même je n'aie pas été formé à transgresser l'usage : j'utilise « on » ; vrai, l'usage de « nous » dans ce contexte me donnera l'impression de quelque chose d'inhabituel, cependant conscient comme je le suis de l'extravagance qui réside en la destitution du pronom légitime pour le remplacer par un pronom à tout faire, conscient de la complexité additionnelle que cela amène dans le langage, je n'aurais aucune objection, et verrais cette occurrence comme un pas de plus vers la restitution  à ce pronom de sa place normale dans le langage.

Comment: @petitrien Votre correction est discutable; la BDL dit bien que après « bien que » le subjonctif est généralement utilisé ([BDL](bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4238
) et de même beaucoup de grammairiens français ; cependant ce n'est pas l'avis de tout le monde ; considérer cette réponse par exemple [« bien que » et le subjonctif](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/33201/17649), et il y a d'autres personnes sur le FSE qui partagent ces avis (il n'y a aucun doute sur la formation dans mon texte).

Comment: Je m'étonne que vous, l'homme de la Règle, l'homme des jugements sans appel, qui fulminez vos avis du haut de votre Olympe, soyez d'une telle indulgence envers vous-même. Mais j'aime mieux citer un de vos commentaires que j'ai trouvé dans le renvoi que vous indiquez : "je ne considère pas mon niveau d'éducation comme exceptionnel et toute ma vie j'ai trouvé naturel l'emploi du subjonctif après « bien que » et l'ai respecté scrupuleusement" (scripsit LPH). Alors, lequel des deux LPH a raison?

Comment: @petitrien Vous voyez bien qu'il ne s'agit pas que mes opinions dans cette question : la référence que je cite mentionne des grammairiens de métier, ce que je suis loin d'être (Damourette & Pichon -> Mary-Annick Morel.) et ce ne sont pas les seuls. Qu'est-ce que je dois comprendre d'emblée ? Des avancées ont été faites dans ce domaine ? Dois-je les rejeter ? Je ne tiens pas aux règles autrement que dans les limites où elles ont une justification logique, dans les limites où elles servent un but réel. (champ 1)

Comment: @petitrien  Quelle est votre contre-indication ou tout au moins votre position ? Il serait utile de savoir cela de quelqu'un de plus qui semble avoir une connaissance du sujet. (fin)

Comment: Ma position est simple : en français moderne, "bien que" est suivi d'un verbe au subjonctif.

Comment: Comme à ton habitude, tu condamnes les transgressions d'un supposé français « pur » et en même temps tu ne sais pas éviter les anglicismes tels que *majorité de personnes françaises* (majorité de Français) ou *ils insisteront que le pronom* (ils insisteront sur le fait que le pronom) et les erreurs de genre comme *cet occurrence*.

Comment: @jlliagre On n'est pas habitué à « majorités de personnes », je le concède et on peut très bien se demander pourquoi l'utiliser quand « une majorité de Français suffit » mais je crois que cela fait partie des constructions libres ; « cet » est une erreur de frappe ; cependant, la troisième est impardonnable : je n'ai pas relu suffisamment. Merci de signaler tout ça.

Comment: Merci de signaler ou merci d'avoir signalé ? Merci.

Comment: @Dimitris « Merci d'avoir signalé » s'applique à un cas particulier où à tous les cas qui précèdent. « Merci de signaler », comme c'est un présent, me semble prendre la valeur d'un présent d'habitude, merci de l'avoir fait et de continuer à le faire. Cependant dans l'utilisation particulière que j'en ai fait « tout ça » semble référer aux seules fautes de cette réponse et cela  ne correspond pas bien. Il vaut mieux éviter cette forme douteuse; dans le cas présent dire « Merci d'avoir signalé tout ça. » ou bien quelque chose comme « Merci de signaler *les fautes. » (pratique habituelle).