# "Je veux un mouton qui vive longtemps." contre "Je veux un mouton qui vivrait longtemps."

Tags: temps-grammatical, subjonctif, subordonnées

> Celui-là est trop vieux. Je veux un mouton qui vive longtemps. ([Le Petit Prince](http://microtop.ca/lepetitprince/chapitre02.html), Antoine de Saint-Exupéry)

https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-93819.php

> Au subjonctif : le subjonctif est utilisé pour un fait envisagé mais
> non encore réel ni effectif.
>
> 1- Après les verbes de volonté: vouloir- exiger - désirer - souhaiter
> ...

Quand pourrait-on reformuler une telle phrase comme ci-dessous (si l'on peut le faire) ?

> Je veux un mouton qui *vivra* longtemps.
>
> Je veux un mouton qui *vivrait* longtemps.

Comment: Je veux un mouton qui vivrait longtemps si je n'en faisais pas aussitôt un méchoui.

Comment: Similaire à: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26052/un-verbe-au-subjonctif-sans-que

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans le premier cas, la personne qui parle le fait selon le point de vue de quelqu'un qui sait qu'il existe des moutons qui vivent longtemps et elle en veut un dont on sait qu'il vivra longtemps. Dans le second cas, son point de vue est celui de la personne qui ne sait pas si un mouton peut vraiment vivre longtemps, donc le conditionnel ; peut être y en a-t-il mais peut être aussi ça n'existe pas.